# Use jquery append to clone hidden html repeatedly

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I've got a form and I need to optionally repeat (clone and append to) a big block of form fields over and over.

So, what I've done is put in a hidden div in the page with the code I would want to copy inside, and then I basically want the user to be able to click a button that says "add" and it adds these blank form fields under the last lot for as many times as they want.

The html I want to clone is as follows:

```
 <div style="display: none;">
        <div class="grab-me">
          <input name="foo[]" />
          <input name="bar[]" />
          <input name="oth[]" />
        </div>
 </div>
```

The jquery I have at the moment is:

```
$(function(){
        $('.add-member').live("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(e);
            var grab = $('.grab-me');
            grab.appendTo('#register');

        });
    });
```

But what that is doing is duplicating the form fields on each click of the button. So I click once, it adds the form fields in once as expected. Click the button again, it adds the form fields in twice this time, click again, it adds three sets of form fields in!

I just want it to add the one set of form fields in once, on each click.

Any advice would be really gratefully received!

Comment: Don't use `.live()` anymore, it's deprecated. Use `.on()` instead, but read the documentation before you do.

Comment: Thanks Jack, i'm well aware of the that but the client is using 1.6.3 and does not wish to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because once it's copied, you then have two `.grab-me` elements. You should remove the class after cloning the element:

```
var grab = $('.grab-me')
    .clone()
    .removeClass('grab-me')
    .appendTo('#register');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do, the easiest that comes to my mind is add the .first() call:

```
$(function(){
        $('.add-member').live("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(e);
            var grab = $('.grab-me').first().clone();
            grab.appendTo('#register');
        });
});
```

The problem you are encountered is after you add it the first time you end up with two divs that have the .grab-me class, so your jquery grabs both.

Comment: It still has the same problem that is adds one more set than it should each time you press it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Or change the last line to `$("#register .grab-me").removeClass("grab-me");`. Easier than cloning :)

Comment: You know, I had that as my first answer! But then I thought it seemed better to just grab the first item.

Comment: @John really? It should only grab a single element from the list. That is strange.

Comment: That current code block above only adds the html once. Subsequent clicks do nothing. Odd.

Comment: looks like .appendTo() will move your object not clone it if you are appending only to a single item is why. Let me edit the code, yo have to clone it after all.

Answer (score 0):

$('.grab-me').eq(0) in order to get just one form (the first form with the class grab-me)

```
$(function(){
        $('.add-member').live("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(e);
            var grab = $('.grab-me').eq(0);
            grab.appendTo('#register');

        });
    });
```

Comment: That only adds the html once and then doesn't work again. Thanks for the reply btw!